# O que seria um Node na Godot Engine?

Tags: jogos, gdscript

Estou [estudando](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/scripting_first_script.html#project-setup) a respeito do Godot e me deparei com um termo chamado *Node* que pode ser criado dentro do projeto do game na Godot como ilustrado na imagem abaixo:

[image: interface godot node]

Este termo me deixou com algumas duvidas, e mesmo eu lendo na doc ainda não consegui deixar bem claro para mim sua aplicabilidade dentro do projeto, portanto gostaria de ter essas respostas.

## Dúvidas

- O que seria um Node?
- O Node tem ligação com as classes `Node` e `Node2D`?
- Existe relação com as scenes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os nós (Nodes) são os blocos de construção, eles podem ser atribuídos como filhos de outro nó, resultando em um arranjo de árvore (tree). Um determinado nó pode conter qualquer número de nós como filhos com a exigência de que todos os irmãos (filhos diretos de um nó) tenham nomes exclusivos.

> Existe relação com as scenes?

Uma árvore de nós é chamada de cena (scene). As cenas podem ser salvas no disco e depois instanciadas em outras cenas, um exemplo básico de árvore de nós, Level01 é uma cena e Coin é outra, dentro de Level01 foi instanciado 5 cenas de Coin.tscn

Level01.tscn

```
Level01 (Node2D)
├───Player (CharacterBody2D)
│   ├───CollisionShape2D
│   └───Sprites (Sprite2D)
│
├───BackgroundMusic (AudioStreamPlayer2D)
├───FailedMusic (AudioStreamPlayer2D)
├───TileMap
│
├───Coin (cena filha de Coin.tscn)
├───Coin (cena filha de Coin.tscn)
├───Coin (cena filha de Coin.tscn)
├───Coin (cena filha de Coin.tscn)
└───Coin (cena filha de Coin.tscn)
```

Coin.tscn

```
Coin (Area2D)
├───AnimatedSprite2D
└───CollisionShape2D
```

> O Node tem ligação com as classes Node e Node2D?

O Node normal não é afetado pela física, o único objetivo é servir como um bloco para você organizar algo que não tenha relação com a física, todos outros nós são herdados do Node "cru", inclusive o Node2D e Node3D.

Um nó adicionado em uma cena funciona semelhante a um objeto instanciado em outras linguagens, tanto que é possível acessa-lo em outros nós, podendo acessar suas propriedades

> O que seria um Node?

Como já expliquei, os nós são semelhantes a instâncias de objetos, você pode criar scripts para cada nó, criando um nó chamado Player (como no exemplo acima), se o player for cair em um abismo e você desejar parar o som de fundo você poderá controlar o nó AudioStreamPlayer2D (no exemplo acima nomeei de BackgroundMusic), então no Player (`CharacterBody2D`) adicionamos algo como:

```py
extends CharacterBody2D

# Pega a instância do nó BackgroundMusic
@onready var bg_music = $"../BackgroundMusic" as AudioStreamPlayer2D

# Pega a instância do nó FailedMusic
@onready var failed_music = $"../FailedMusic" as AudioStreamPlayer2D

...

# player caiu em um buraco
fun _process(delta):
  if <lógica checar se o player caiu em um abismo>:
     # para a música de fundo do level atual
     bg_music.stop()

     # toda a música de quando falha no level
     failed_music.play()
     ...
```

Nós também podem ser tratados semelhantes a classes, para isso pode usar `class_name` no começo do script, seria como estender a classe de tipo de nó, do qual você poderia criar propriedade própria, imagine que você quer definir status para o seu player, para que esse status seja verificável por outros scripts, você poderia usar constantes ou um `enum` para isso, ficando algo como no nó Player:

```py
extends CharacterBody2D
class_name Player

enum {WALKING, RUNNING, IDLE, FALLING, JUMPING, FAILED}

var status = IDLE

...
```

Então nesse caso você poderia fazer o caminho inverso, os outros nós pegam a instância do *Player* e verificam a variável status como se fosse uma propriedade de um objeto instanciado (semelhante em outras linguagens), você poderia criar um nó simples que contenha os scripts para controlar toda ou qualquer música dentro da cena, esse nó não precisa de física, logo pode usar o nó simples (`Node`), uma estrutura semelhante:

Level01.tscn

```
Level01 (Node2D)
├───MusicControl (Node)
│
├───Player (CharacterBody2D)
│   ├───CollisionShape2D
│   └───Sprites (Sprite2D)
│
├───BackgroundMusic (AudioStreamPlayer2D)
├───FailedMusic (AudioStreamPlayer2D)

...
```

No nó nomeado de *MusicControl* você poderia criar um script próprio (ou pelo menos as funções que vai usar, e esse script pode ser adicionado em outros leveis (fases) adicionando em um nó (Node) independente sem precisar misturar em nós que não fazem parte do contexto necessário, então no script adicionado ao nó você teria algo como:

```py
extends CharacterBody2D

# variáveis com @export são controladas no inspetor do IDE
@export var bg: AudioStreamPlayer2D
@export var fail: AudioStreamPlayer2D
@export var character: CharacterBody2D

func play_fail():
     # para a música de fundo do árvore atual
     bg_music.stop()

     # toda a música de quando falha
     failed_music.play()

func play_background():
     # para outras músicas
     failed_music.stop()

     # toda música de fundo da árvore atual
     bg_music.play()

func stop_all():
     # para outras músicas
     failed_music.stop()

     # toda música de fundo da árvore atual
     bg_music.play()

func _process(delta):
  if character.state == Player.FAILED:
     play_fail()
  else:
     play_background()
```

Claro que isso tudo não é o ideal a se fazer, é apenas uma forma ilustrativa de como entender o comportamento de acessar as propriedades, então voltando ao que importa, no nó MusicControl o script irá rodar e ficar checando o status o player, note que para checar os enums da classe usamos `Player.` que é o mesmo nome de `class_name Player`, então na if checamos `Player.FAILED`.

Nós também podem ser adicionados dinamicamente, via código, a outros nós usando o `.new()`, que é um método para todos tipo de nós, ao usa-lo você irá instanciar um nó.

Então algum script de uma cena (scene) você poderia chamar:

```py
# Cria um novo Sprite2D.
var sprite2d = Sprite2D.new()

# Adiciona ao node atual
add_child(sprite2d)
```

Se você criou uma nó com `class_name Moeda` (representando uma moeda coletável no jogo), você pode adiciona-la via código assim:

```py
var moeda = Moeda.new()
add_child(moeda)
```

Fora isso também existe o *design pattern* chamado `State`, mas isso vai além da parte de programação, é uma forma de trabalhar, mas o que importa entender é que faz exatamente o uso explicado dos recursos usados acima (claro que também faz uso de outros recursos nativos, mas isso tudo vai além), usado para controlar animações, estados, habilidades dos personagens ou objetos.